# Changing X axis on ggplot logarithm

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display a graph showing the log10 transformed values of some data. When creating a violin graph with the below code:

```
tt <- EditedDF1 %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=ct_marshallFAC, y=log10(uchl1_d1_pgml), fill = EditedDF1$ct_marshallFAC)) + 
geom_violin() +
geom_boxplot(width=0.1, outlier.shape = NA, fill="white") +
theme_classic() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 20)) +
labs(x="", y= "Log UCHL1(pg/ml)") +
ylim(-3.5, 6)  +
theme(legend.position="none")+
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("I", "II", "III-IV", "V-VI")) +
geom_hline(yintercept = 1.568, colour = "red", linetype="dotted" )
```

My problem is the y axis gives a value of -3, -2, -1, 0 when what I want it to show is the actual value the log10 would equate to. For instance -1 would be 0.1, 0 would be 1, 1 would be 10 and so on.

I have chosen to display the log-transformed data as I have multiple panels of data. However I feel the reader would be better able to understand if I gave the actual values on the y axis.

Many thanks.
Dan W

Answer (score 0):

Take out your `ylim(-3.5, 6)` and use ggplot's `scale_y_log10` instead with limits there:

```
library(ggplot2)

EditedDF1 <- data.frame(ct_marshallFAC = rep(c("I", "II", "III-IV", "V-VI"),10), uchl1_d1_pgml =runif(40)*100)


tt <- EditedDF1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=ct_marshallFAC, y=log10(uchl1_d1_pgml), 
             fill = EditedDF1$ct_marshallFAC)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, outlier.shape = NA, fill="white") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 20)) +
  labs(x="", y= "UCHL1(pg/ml)") +
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("I", "II", "III-IV", "V-VI")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.568, colour = "red", linetype="dotted" ) +
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(exp(-3.5), exp(6)))
```

[image: Graph]

Edit: I've never had someone tell me that a logarithmic scale is confusing...I'd just use what you had to begin with and keep the label to reflect that the values are logarithmic.